# Hive: Creating smaller table from big table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I currently have a Hive table that has 1.5 billion rows. I would like to create a smaller table (using the same table schema) with about 1 million rows from the original table. Ideally, the new rows would be randomly sampled from the original table, but getting the top 1M or bottom 1M of the original table would be ok, too. How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [climbage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213901/climbage) suggested earlier, you could probably best use Hive's [built-in sampling methods](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Sampling).

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table_sample 
SELECT * FROM my_table 
TABLESAMPLE (1m ROWS) t;
```

This syntax was [introduced in Hive 0.11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3401). If you are running an older version of Hive, you'll be confined to using the `PERCENT` syntax like so.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_table_sample 
SELECT * FROM my_table 
TABLESAMPLE (1 PERCENT) t;
```

You can change the percentage to match you specific sample size requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how to use the sampling syntax? I read through the Hive page you mentioned but am still puzzled. For example, I'd like to create a table of 100,000 rows (out of 1.5 billion). I tried INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE small_table AS SELECT * FROM big_table TABLESAMPLE (100k ROWS) t, but I get a parse error. I also tried the literal "100000" in place of "100k".

Comment: What version of Hive are you using? I believe the above syntax was introduced in 0.11. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3401

Comment: I am using Hive 0.10.0.24: hive-hwi-0.10.0.24.jar

Comment: In that case you'll only have support for the 'percent' syntax. I've updated my answer to include an example of that also.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm kind of disappointed by the Hive documentation. In the first link you gave me (http://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-sampling.html), it mentions the TABLESAMPLE (n ROWS) syntax, but it doesn't say it's only supported in 0.11.

Comment: Hive documentation could certainly be better. Patches welcome! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new table with the same schema as your original table.

Then use `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <tablename> <select statement>`

The SELECT statement will need to query your original table, use LIMIT to only get 1M results.

Comment: Adding on to this, see [sampling in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-sampling.html) for help on building a select statement with a smaller sample size

Comment: Would this work? CREATE TABLE small_table AS SELECT * FROM big_table LIMIT 1000000

Comment: No. You'll need to create your table schema first as a separate statement. Then execute INSERT OVERWRITE afterwards.

Comment: What does "CREATE TABLE small_table AS SELECT * FROM big_table" do, and why won't it do what your statement does?

Comment: Also, is there an easy way to create a new table with exactly the same schema as another table? I'd prefer not to type out the entire schema again as part of the CREATE TABLE command.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 CREATE TABLE small_table AS SELECT * FROM big_table LIMIT 1000000, would work for sure. If you want copy just schema use: CREATE TABLE small_table LIKE big_table;

Answer (score 1):

This query will pull out top 1M rows and overwrite them in a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, ....
  FROM original_table 
  WHERE (if you want to put any condition) limit 100000;
```