# How to sample for each group in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a large table in hive that has 1.5 bil+ values. One of the columns is `category_id`, which has ~20 distinct values. I want to sample the table such that I have 1 mil values for each category.

I checked out [Random sample table with Hive, but including matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190498/random-sample-table-with-hive-but-including-matching-rows) and [Hive: Creating smaller table from big table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117967/hive-creating-smaller-table-from-big-table) and I figured out how to get a random sample from the entire table, but I'm still unable to figure out how to get a sample for each `category_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to sample your table in multiple files. You might want to check [Hive bucketing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL+BucketedTables) or [Dynamic partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions) to balance your records between multiple folder/files.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` hive function can be used for random sampling in hive. However, it's quite slow with a large dataset. Hence first create a partition of the group you want to do a sample (category_id in your case) on. Following is the query that would sample 1 million random rows for each category_id.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY rand()) as rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        CLUSTER BY category_id -- partition by category_id
    ) as subquery
) as t
WHERE t.rn <= 1000000;
```

**Explanation**:

- CLUSTER BY: This statement partitions the data by group(category_id in this case). It ensures that rows with the same group values (same category_id values) are colocated in the same reducer, making it easier to sample efficiently within each partition.
- ROW_NUMBER(): Replacing RANK() with ROW_NUMBER() simplifies the query and avoids unnecessary tie-breaking computations required by RANK(). We are still using ORDER BY RAND() within the window function, but because we have partitioned the data, it will only sort within each partition, making it more efficient.

By partitioning the data and using ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK(), we can significantly improve the performance of the query, especially on large datasets.