# Select single random sample from group by in Hive

Tags: random, hive, group-by

I have a table that looks like so:

```
Name      Age       Num_Hobbies     Num Shoes
Jane      31        10              2
Bob       23        3               4
Jane      60        2               200
Jane      31        100             6
Bob       10        8               7
etc etc
```

I would like to group this table by Name and Age, and at random pick one row from the rest of the columns.

In pandas, I would do the following:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Age']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1))
```

In hive, I know how to create the group, but not how to choose a single random sample from group.

I saw this question on stack overflow: [How to sample for each group in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887317/how-to-sample-for-each-group-in-hive)

However, I do not understand how to apply Dynamic partitions or Hive bucketing to select a single sample from a group.

Comment: Pick the top row after grouping without ordering the grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rank()` or `row_number()` with `rand()`

```
select * from 
(
       select name,age,rank() (partition by name,age order by rand()) as rank
       from table         
) t 
where rank = 1
```

Comment: When I tried this, my rank was "1" for all of the entries

Comment: Also, this would not select a truly random sample - just first row from each (and if they are already ordered, would this mangle the order enough to call the sample random?)

Comment: order by rand() should randomize the rows

Comment: not "rank() (partition by name,age order by rand()) as rank" but "rank()  over (partition by name,age order by rand()) as rank"

Answer (score 1):

rand() function is quite slow when one is working with large data. In such cases create a partition first to optimize your query. Following is a more efficient query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name, age ORDER BY rand()) as rn
    FROM (
        SELECT name, age
        FROM table
        CLUSTER BY name, age -- partition by name and age
    ) as subquery
) as t
WHERE t.rn=1;
```

**Explanation of the changes**:

- CLUSTER BY: This statement partitions the data by name and age. It ensures that rows with the same name and age values are colocated in the same reducer, making it easier to sample efficiently within each partition.
- ROW_NUMBER(): Replacing RANK() with ROW_NUMBER() simplifies the query and avoids unnecessary tie-breaking computations required by RANK(). We are still using ORDER BY RAND() within the window function, but because we have partitioned the data, it will only sort within each partition, making it more efficient.

By partitioning the data and using ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK(), we can significantly improve the performance of the query, especially on large datasets.